# Infinite Fibonacci word is not periodic

Tags: combinatorics

How can one prove that the infinite [Fibonacci word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word) is not periodic?
PS. Maybe, beginning from some position.

Comment: http://fibophilia.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/fibonacci-word-is-not-periodic/

Comment: @Sharkos: Make it an answer (CW, if you don't want credit for it).

Comment: @Sharkos: I don't understand why the limit of a sequence consisting of rational numbers cannot be an irrational number.

Comment: @user64494 The contradiction is the fact that the FW is periodic. If the FW is periodic, the frequency of $0's$ is the number of zeroes in a period, divided by the length of the period. This is a rational number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the page http://fibophilia.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/fibonacci-word-is-not-periodic/ for a few arguments. (Someone with time can write it up if they want.)